# Selenium with Python: How to check if URL is valid

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-requests, urllib

I have this functional test that gets a url from an href.

But how do I test test if it is valid (ie: 200/success and not 404)

```
def test_card_links(self):
    """Click card, make sure url is valid"""
    card_link = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#app-scoop-panel a').get_attribute('href');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you retrieve the *`href`* attribute as *card_link* you can check the validity of the link using either of the following approaches:

- Using *`requests.head()`*:

  ```
  import requests

  def test_card_links(self):
      """Click card, make sure url is valid"""
      card_link = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#app-scoop-panel a').get_attribute('href')
      request_response = requests.head(card_link)
      status_code = request_response.status_code
      if status_code == 200:
          print("URL is valid/up")
      else:
          print("URL is invalid/down")
  ```
- Using *`urlopen()`*:

  ```
  import requests
  import urllib

  def test_card_links(self):
      """Click card, make sure url is valid"""
      card_link = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#app-scoop-panel a').get_attribute('href')
      status_code = urllib.request.urlopen(card_link).getcode()
      if status_code == 200:
          print("URL is valid/up")
      else:
          print("URL is invalid/down")
  ```